# What is the maximum recommended number of open file descriptors on my vmware which is currently 1024?

Tags: vmware, cpu

```
*-core 
description: Motherboard

product: 440BX Desktop Reference Platform 
vendor: Intel Corporation 
physical id: 0 
version: None 
serial: None 
*-firmware 
description: BIOS 
physical id: 0 
version: 6.00 
date: 04/14/2014 
size: 87KiB 
capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot 

*-cpu:0 
description: CPU 
product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz 
vendor: Intel Corp. 
physical id: 4 
bus info: cpu@0 
version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz 
slot: CPU socket #0 
size: 2600MHz 
capacity: 4230MHz 
width: 64 bits



The current limits are : 
core file size (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited 
file size (blocks, -f) unlimited 
max locked memory (kbytes, -l) unlimited 
max memory size (kbytes, -m) unlimited 
open files (-n) 1024 
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 1 
stack size (kbytes, -s) 8192 
cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited 
max user processes (-u) 1418 
virtual memory (kbytes, -v) unlimited 


$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2593.993
BogoMIPS:              5187.98
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              35840K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

Comment: On my laptop it's currently 790447, on my server 364709, quite a bit more.

Comment: @Jos could you tell me how to change it? like where the config file is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your CPU. It's a setting for how many open file descriptors you can have. It can be shown with `ulimit -n`. The default is 1024 per process.

The max limit a user can have can be set in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

The currently configured system max can be seen with the command

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
601126
```

This value is the total for the system, not per process.

This can be changed by writing a new value to the same location, for instance `echo 1000000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/file-max`. This is the upper limit.

The value in use is shown in `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr`, which has three numbers. The first is currently in use file descriptors, second is allocated, but free, descriptors, and the third is the system configured maximum.

The uliit per process can be changed by the user, up to the maximum described in `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
[~]$ ulimit -n
1024
[~]$ ulimit -n 2048
[~]$ ulimit -n
2048
```

In addition, you have two kinds of limits. Hard and soft. You can play with the soft limits, but only root can raise  hard limits. To show hard limits, run `ulimit -H -n`. The user can *lower* hard limits, but never raise them, even back to the initial value if decreased.

```
[~]$ ulimit -H -n
4096
[~]$ ulimit -H -n 2048
[~]$ ulimit -H -n 4096
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
[~]$
```

If you have any more question about limits, I suggest you ask a more specific question, as it was rather wide open. There's not *recommended* value; different processes require different approaches. The defaults are sane for most applications, whilst some applications may run in to issues.

The short answer is not to worry unless you run into problems.